# What is the algorithmic runtime of the removeFirst() method in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, linked-list

Ok, so I know there exist some really good threads about the cost of different operations on the `Collection` interface. [When to use LinkedList<> over ArrayList<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist/322742#322742) gives a great overview of the difference between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`. But after reading that thread I am still unsure of one thing:

Is the algorithmic runtime of `removeFirst()/pollFirst()` and `removeLast()/pollLast()` O(1) or do i have to use an `Iterator` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list.

So removal of the head or tail is O(1).